# Images are not loading after deploying angular app on github pages

Tags: angular, image, github, deployment, github-pages

I deployed a test project on github pages using these commands:

```
ng build --prod --base-href https://<profile_name>.github.io/<repo_name>/
ngh --dir=dist/scrabble
```

Everything works fine except images (on localhost every image is loading).

---

outputPath in angular.json:

```
"outputPath": "dist/scrabble/",
```

assets in angular.json:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets"
],
```

assets folder with images is located in `<project_folder>/src/assets`

one example of image tag which works perfectly on localhost but doesn't load on github pages:

```
  <img src="../../../assets/scaledlogo.png" routerLink="/menu" />
```

Comment: Can you still serve the file in the local ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I don't know what it means

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If all your images are in your assets folder you can just remove the `../`s form the path.

```
 <img src="assets/scaledlogo.png" routerLink="/menu" />
```

So the issue is everything gets transpiled and minified and the assets folder is no longer 3 directories back. Angular knows where your assets folder is if you are running it locally or its deployed and does not need the relative path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass **--deploy-url** option. in your case it should be

```sh
ng build --prod --base-href https://<profile_name>.github.io/<repo_name>/ --deploy-url=https://<profile_name>.github.io/<repo_name>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "../" in front and mention the path starting from the assets folder
Below will solve your problem

```
<img src="assets/scaledlogo.png" routerLink="/menu" />
```

In case if you have additional folder inside the assets go on with that path.
For Example:

```
<img src="assets/images/leave-procedure/admin1.png" width="400" height="150">
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

A list of things to check:

1. Check the dist folder if the assets are there.
2. Try to update the deployed link if it works with a different path

   - If it does work, it's a problem with the path setup possibly under the configuration files like angular.json
3. Check the Network tab for any error like redirection issues

   - Most likely a redirection code in the back-end. Try changing the file name.

Answer (score 0):

See this guide section: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages 
You need to set the base ref property:
ng build --output-path docs --base-href /your_project_name/